# How to remove downloads

Tags: storage, downloading

On my Nexus 7, I see in Storage that Downloads are taking 50.56 MB. I tap Downloads and then see "No items".

How do I remove these 50 MB?

Answer (score 1):

1. Open the app `My Files`
2. Tap `All Files`
3. You may see `Device Storage` and possibly `SD memory card`
4. Tap either (or both)
5. Tap `Download` (or `download`)
6. Select files individually, or tap the menu button then `Select all`
7. Tap the trash can icon